# Unable to Access pytest Test Features Without Modifying sys.path

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, system

I am working on a Python project where I have the following project structure:

```
project_directory/
├── src/
│   └── my_functions.py   # Contains functions to test
├── tests/
│   └── test_my_functions.py   # pytest test file
└── other_files_and_folders/   # Additional files or folders in the project
```

In the `project_directory`, I have a `src` directory containing the source code with functions that I want to test using pytest. The `tests` directory holds the pytest test file `test_my_functions.py`, which contains the test functions.

Initially, to import and access the functions from the `src` directory in the `test_my_functions.py` file, I used the following code to modify the Python path:

```py
import sys
import os

# Get the path of the current directory (where test_my_functions.py is located)
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Add the parent directory of 'src' to the Python path
parent_directory = os.path.dirname(current_directory)
sys.path.append(parent_directory)
```

While this approach works, I am seeking a cleaner and more efficient way to access the pytest test features without explicitly modifying the Python path in the test script. I want to ensure that my test script can import the modules from the `src` directory seamlessly while following best practices and avoiding any potential pitfalls.

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve this without explicitly modifying the Python path in the test script? I am looking for insights and suggestions on how to accomplish this while maintaining a clean and maintainable project structure. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using plugins, try [pytest-pythonpath](https://github.com/ericpalakovichcarr/pytest-pythonpath).

Install:

```bash
pip install pytest-pythonpath
```

Then create a file called pyproject.toml:

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_paths = ["src", "other_files_and_folders"]
```

Then in your test_my_functions.py:

```py
import my_functions

# tests to follow...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use pytest plugins, then another alternative is to set PYTHONPATH environment variable before running the test. I prefer to use `make` and `Makefile`. Here is my `Makefile`:

```
# Makefile
.PHONY: test
test:
    PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/src:${PWD}/other_files_and_folders pytest
```

Run the test:

```bash
make test
```

You can also create a shell script (or a Windows .cmd file) to set the PYTHONPATH, then run pytest.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, I placed the Makefile `project_directory` and copied the code that you have like this `PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/src:${PWD}/other_files_and_folders pytest` but it still does not work and I get the message: `# make test
make: Nothing to be done for 'test'.`

Comment: In `Makefile`, make sure that you indent the line after `test:` using a tab, not spaces.