# Python pytest cannot find modules inside src directory

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, containers, jupyter

I'm facing a challenge with my Python project setup that involves module imports, testing using `pytest`, and working with Jupyter Notebook. My project directory structure looks like this:

```
project/
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
├── pyproject.toml
├── jupyter_notebook_config.py
├── notebooks/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── my_module.py
│   │   └── module_name.c
│   ├── tests/
│   │   ├── test_my_module.py
│   │   └── test_sub_module.py
│   └── my_notebook.ipynb
└── ...
```

Inside the `pyproject.toml` file, I've configured the Python paths for `pytest` like this using the `pytest-pythonpath` plugin:

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
python_paths = ["src"]
```

My Docker container is based on the `python:3.11` image and uses a Dockerfile similar to the following:

```
FROM python:3.11

# Copy the requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Install the dependencies from the requirements.txt file
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Copy the pyproject.toml file to the container
COPY pyproject.toml /app/pyproject.toml

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Run pip install -e . to install pyproject.toml
RUN pip install -e .

# Expose Jupyter Notebook port
EXPOSE 8888

# Copy the custom Jupyter configuration file
COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /root/.jupyter/

# Run Jupyter Notebook on container startup
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

I've attempted to address module import issues by adding the following code at the beginning of my test files and notebooks:

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'notebooks/src')))
```

However, despite these efforts, I'm encountering problems where both `pytest` and Jupyter Notebook cannot locate the modules inside the `src` directory. How can I properly configure my project so that both `pytest` and Jupyter Notebook can access the modules within the `src` directory for importing, testing, and working with notebooks?

To provide additional context, I've encountered similar issues with module imports and working with compiled C extensions and Python files. I've referred to the following discussions for guidance:

1. [Unable to Access pytest Test Features Without Modifying sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759473/unable-to-access-pytest-test-features-without-modifying-sys-path)
2. [Importing Compiled C Extensions & Python Files from Folder Dynamically in Jupyter Notebook](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/importing-compiled-c-extensions-python-files-from-folder-dynamically-in-jupyter-notebook/20811)

Additionally, when attempting to run `pytest`, I'm encountering an error message like the one below:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.4, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /app
plugins: pythonpath-0.7.4, anyio-3.7.1
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                    

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________ ERROR collecting tests/test_my_functions_demo.py _______________
ImportError while importing test module '/app/tests/test_my_functions_demo.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_my_functions_demo.py:2: in <module>
    from my_functions_demo import add, subtract
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_functions_demo'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/test_my_functions_demo.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.15s ===============================
```

To illustrate the issue further:

**Working Solution:**

```py
import src.module_name

# Calculate lengths and elements for the range from 1 to 15 using Cython
sample_range, lengths, elements = src.module_name.calculate_lengths_cython(1, 15)
```

**Not Working Solution:**

```py
import module_name

# Calculate lengths and elements for the range from 1 to 15 using Cython
sample_range, lengths, elements = module_name.calculate_lengths_cython(1, 15)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual layout in the container is: your pytest log shows no `notebook` folder for tests, while your `sys.path.insert` attempt has one containing `src`.

Comment: that was a typo it should have been `notebooks` instead of `notebook` sorry about that